# Next.js ISR and a synchronized navigation menu

Tags: javascript, next.js

this is my first post.

I am trying to find a resource to help me out with my issue but to no avail and thus I decided to reach out here.

I am wondering how do people on their next.js projects handle things like for example navbar menus and ISR?

I have a website that consists of thousands of products/pages and I am trying to find a way to keep a common menu in all these pages synchronized.

So far, I have included the getInitialProps method in the _app.js that performs an api call to retrieve the header menu and the footer menu and returns them as props. Inside the _app.js I have a  and a  component to which I pass the menu props retrieved from the getInitialProps. This way I have one point of reference from which I retrieve the menu and thus I don’t have to include it in every page route/dynamic route.

Now, with this method, I face a problem during the revalidation process since different route types have different revalidation timers. I have pages where the revalidation could be 24 hours since they rarely change and other pages can have 10 mins since their content gets more often updated. This results in users having different menu items as they navigate through the website when a menu has been updated.

This gets even worst with the new on-demand revalidation feature to which I am trying to migrate. Using the on-demand revalidation, I removed the revalidation timers to avoid unnecessary API calls. After implementing the revalidate API as mentioned in the documentation and including webhooks to my Laravel backend application now the problem I have is obviously that revalidating a specific slug, updated the menu and the rest of the website has the previous menu.

I know I am writing a lot here but I am trying to explain the issue in as detail as possible.

So, to the point then. How do you guys handle such situations? I read on a thread somewhere that some people go about retrieving the menu client side. But isn’t this harmful to SEO?
Again, sorry for the wall of text. Very curious to hear your approaches.

Comment: There are many ways to do those things. You can use react-bootstrap for bootstrap navbars and think you can use redux or communicate among components. And can use a common layout and import navbar or footer components there.

Comment: That would mean loading the menus on the client side right? And storing them in a "global state". Wouldnt this be a bad thing for SEO since the crawler wouldn't be able to read the menu? Is there a non-client-side method to do this with static generation?

Comment: As far as I know, it would be really hard to load nav-related js from the backend. The reason is jquery and bootstrap are a bit harder to load from the backend. I also like to know  if there are a way to do it :)

Comment: The problem is not the js part. The issue is the content of the menu (the menu items) retrieved from the API. This is what I want to find in terms of how to keep it synced across all pages regardless of the revalidation timers.

Comment: If the content of the nav menu is part of each page, and the data for that menu changes, doesn't that mean you would have to revalidate _each_ page? If you want to keep using ISR, it's either that or rendering the nav client-side. Alternatively, you could move to SSR instead.

Comment: @juliomalves Yeah, I guess so. In the case of a small website with a few pages, I guess it's okay to revalidate the entire website. In my case with a few thousand pages client-side is the only path it seems.  I am not sure how much this affects SEO though.